# Error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c')" with vue-form-generator and Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to integrate vue-form-generator into an application I've recently taken over, but I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve.

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c')
    at Proxy.r (vfg.js:7:174974)
```

Steps I've taken so far:

1. added the necessary dependencies in my index file:

   ```
    <script src="js/other.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import * as VueFormGenerator from './js/lib/vfg.js';
        var app = Vue.createApp(Application)
            .use(VueFormGenerator)
            .mount("#Application");
    </script>
   ```
2. incorporated the component:

   ```
   components: {
        // other components
        "vue-form-generator": VueFormGenerator.component
    },
   ```
3. I also included a schema from their documentation [docs](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator)
   Yet, I'm facing the aforementioned error. Has anyone encountered this before or can provide any guidance on how to resolve it?